# How to convert Html to image in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, canvas

I want to convert my page into image, I have try html2canvas for convert HTML to image but is is not working for me because in my HTML some image load from other domain and cross domain image not load in canvas.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a general difficult task. If the html2canvas not work for you, consider to spot the actual reason of that, why is not read that images for example.

Comment: Can you please be more specific and explain why you want to implement converting HTML to image? I believe you want to show some sort of thumbnail.

Comment: Canvas generate perfect when taintTest: false, but when use canvas.toDataURL() it gives error "SecurityError: The operation is insecure."

Comment: Refer - Get ASP.NET VB.NET Website Thumbnail Screenshot - 


link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538375/get-asp-net-vb-net-website-thumbnail-screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I have used [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95439/Get-ASP-NET-C-2-0-Website-Thumbnail-Screenshot)  for a similar task and it works fine.

Comment: It is not an exe. It has source code. In your tags, you have asp.net. So, this should be suitable for you. Moreover, using with Web Handler, you can use it without postback.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i used [this](http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/) to convert HTML to image. You can try it out. It is available for **FREE**.

Hope it works...